# convert time into millisecond in C

Tags: c

I have a list of data formatted as

> 08:01:00.064

Notation: hour,minute,second and millisecond

I need convert them into the notation of: second.millisecond.

Please find my code below,

```
float calculateTime(char *line) {

    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
    int millisecond;
    //transfer from char to int
    hour = ((line[0] - '0')*10 + (line[1] - '0'))*3600;
    minute = ((line[3] - '0')*10 + (line[4] - '0'))*60;
    second = (line[6] - '0')*10 + (line[7] - '0');
    millisecond = (line[9] - '0') *100 + (line[10] - '0') *10 + (line[11] - '0');

    float time;

    time = hour + minute + second + millisecond *0.001;

    return (time);
```

}

There is a problem with my code that the milliseconds will be inaccurate. I think it's due to the float format when calculating.

Result below,

> 37831.945312    source millisecond = 944

The output I expected was

> 37831.945312

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What is an mmsecond?

Comment: Although not your immediate problem, not that an `int` in C could have a maximum value as low as 32767; which you will overflow. Use a `long` instead.

Comment: The correct result should be 37831.944, but my code will result 37831.945312

Comment: OK, mmsecond should be msecond (millisecond). If you make `time` a `double` you get enough precision to have msecs right to 3 digits

Comment: @Walter Tross It works. Thank you Walter Tross

Comment: @Walter Tross  a _mmsecond_ is the 2nd [M&M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%26M%27s) you eat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typical `float` (IEEE754 32 bit) will only be accurate to about 7 significant digits. You exceed that.

A solution? Use a `double` instead. That will give you about 15 significant figures. But note that the result may well still not be *exact*. That's the nature of floating point arithmetic.

A decent solution? Use a `stuct` instead containing the time values. There's one called `tm` in `<time.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies with the lack of precision in the 32 bit `float` type. Use type `double` instead for the time variable. It has the precision you require.